# How to look up value with partial text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to match Address in "summary" with the District on "Sheet1" by using Name in "Sheet1".
The Address column in "summary" contains partial text in the Name column in "Sheet1".
How can I do it?
I have tried =VLOOKUP(E2&"*",Sheet1!A:B,2,TRUE), but it shows NA.
Much appreciated.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: summary]

Comment: Could you please give an example of the string and the corresponding match?

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here. If the delivery_address meets these two criteria:

(1) Always starts with the hotel name (and never prefixed with something else).

(2) Always has a comma after the hotel name (like "Hotel ABC," but not "Hotel ABC ,").

Then the following formula would work:

=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1),E:F,2,FALSE)

In this case, It's looking for the first comma in the address field and returning everything to the left of it, and then it's doing a vlookup on that against your reference data (E:F in my case).

[image]